# LinQ to Xml query and displaying empty elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following Xelemnt that contains a linq query within it. The query works fine but I want to be able to return an empty recruiter element if there are no recruiters within the recruiter list `(List<recruiters>)` for a particular person. Is there any easy way to do this without checking to see if a recruiter element exists for a specific person after the xml has been built and if not then adding it?

```
XElement Person =
                    new XElement("Person",
                    new XElement("title", ""),
                    new XElement("id",""),
                    new XElement("url", ""),
                     (from Recruiter r in recruiters
                        where r.id == p.id
                        select new XElement("Recruiter",
                        new XElement("recruitername", r.recruitername),
                        new XElement("recruiteremail", r.recruiteremail),
                        new XElement("recruiterphone"))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the DefaultIfEmpty method of Enumerable class.
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty.aspx)

```
XElement defaultRecruiter = new XElement("Recruiter");
XElement Person =
                new XElement("Person",
                new XElement("title", ""),
                new XElement("id",""),
                new XElement("url", ""),
                 (from Recruiter r in recruiters
                    where r.id == p.id
                    select new XElement("Recruiter",
                    new XElement("recruitername", r.recruitername),
                    new XElement("recruiteremail", r.recruiteremail),
                    new XElement("recruiterphone"))).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultRecruiter));
```